# Put MSI file to Azure Storage using SAS url

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, intune

I'm uploading a MSI file for MS Intune to the Azure storage. I break the file into chunks and upload them into the repository using the SAS link. When I upload file, I get a successful response. Intune confirms that the file was successfully uploaded.

[image]

But when the computer is synchronized with the Intune, the file is not installed. Intune reports that an error occurred while installing the file (code or reason not specified).

It seems to me that the problem is splitting the file into chuks. But all my efforts to solve this problem have failed.

```
public async Task UploadFile(string fullFilePath, string blobSasUri, int timeout = 60)
{

    var BlockSize = 1024 * 1024; 
    var blocks = new List<String>();

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[BlockSize];

        var bytesRead = 0;
        var blockNumber = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, BlockSize)) > 0)
        {
            var actualBytesRead = new byte[bytesRead];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, actualBytesRead, 0, bytesRead);
            var chunk = blockNumber++;
            var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(chunk.ToString("0000")));
            blocks.Add(blockId);

            await UploadBlock(blobSasUri, blockId, actualBytesRead, timeout);
        }
    }

    await CommitAllBlocks(blobSasUri, blocks,  timeout);

}

private async Task UploadBlock(String sasUrl, String blockId, byte[] contentBytes, int timeout)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient(timeout))
    {
        var blockUrl = String.Format("{0}&comp=block&blockid={1}", sasUrl, blockId);

        var iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        var encodedBody = iso.GetString(contentBytes);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(encodedBody, iso );

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

        var result = await client.PutAsync(blockUrl, content);

    }
}

private HttpClient GetHttpClient(int timeout)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = GetTimeout(timeout);

    return client;
}

private TimeSpan GetTimeout(int specifiedTimeout)
{
    if (specifiedTimeout == 0)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(specifiedTimeout);
}

private async Task CommitAllBlocks(string sasUrl, List<string> blockIds,  int timeout)
{
    using (var client = GetHttpClient(timeout))
    {
        var contentString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><BlockList>";

        foreach (var blockId in blockIds)
        {
            contentString += $"<Latest>{blockId}</Latest>";
        }
        contentString += "</BlockList>";


        HttpContent content = new StringContent(contentString);

        var commitUrl = $"{sasUrl}&comp=blocklist";

        await client.PutAsync(commitUrl, content);
    }
}
```

As an example, I use an example from Microsoft. I checked its performance and it works well. The file is installed on the computer.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/blob/master/LOB_Application/Application_LOB_Add.ps1

Comment: Mother of God. Why? Why not just use the Storage SDK and call UploadBlobAsync?

Comment: Use the Azure Storage SDK don't craft HTTP REST, these might change, SDKs have backward compatibility and much easier.

Comment: Right - as others have questioned - is there a specific reason you're choosing to use REST? And attempting to split the file into your own custom-sized blocks, etc.... (with a very small block size, for some reason)

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code. Do you see the blobs in blob container? One possible problem could be that the blob container in which blobs are present is private. Can you copy the blob URL and paste it in address bar and see if the blob is downloaded successfully?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri https://NAME.blob.core.windows.net/2ca2a439-e281-4799-a3cf-ff8ac29d8fff/e7a49254-555b-4651-9d3f-fa0e48d20191/72e669fa-eb2e-4eb5-aecd-cc70a5598e0b.msi.bin. When I click this link, I download the msi.bin file.

Comment: Ok. Could it be possible that the file is corrupted? I noticed that you're converting a byte array to a string. Can you tell me why you're doing this? Also, please compare the size of the file and that of the uploaded blob.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri file sizes are the same. It's possible that the file is corrupt, but how do I check if I download the msi.bin file? This version of the code is as close as possible to the example from Microsoft. In the original version, I use `new ByteArrayContent (contentBytes);`

Comment: Is there a possibility that you can upload one such file to a public place from where I can download and try your code?

Comment: @ Gaurav Mantri https://transfer.sh/GG8DI/d6d4a397-cf64-488b-88aa-bb59084f364b_temp.bin

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try. Will revert shortly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172204/discussion-between-john-and-gaurav-mantri).